# Insert/Delete Anywhere in a Linked List in C++

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have been learning C++ for a while, and just started looking at linked lists recently. I can construct a template class List with the usual functions insert/remove from back/front. Now I came up with an exercise that asks me to write a function to handle insertions/deletions anywhere in the list.

Please bear in mind that my questions are very basic.

The problem I have is that I see the question as ambiguous. What kind of information does the function require? For instance, for deletion, I can come up with several candidates:
1) delete the first node that has a particular value (argument: value)
2) delete all nodes with a particular value (argument: value)
3) delete a particular node (argument: pointer to that node)
1) and 2) I can easily code. 3) is harder but I can also do it. I just don't see the point in 3). Is it usual to manipulate nodes (outside the list definition) when using lists? As in, is it usual for a program using lists to actually manipulate pointers to the nodes?

What is the usual meaning of "delete anywhere" in this setting?

Similarly, for "insert anywhere", the wording is strange. What does "anywhere" mean? Is the place in the linked list supposed to be given by a particular node?

Comment: Not really clear what you are asking. You want us to guess what was meant by an exercise you read somewhere? You can take a look at the standard containers to see how their interface is made. They usually use iterators

Comment: The function requires some sort of place marker. It can be an int, or better yet, an object that encapsulates a position so you won't have to iterate over the entire list (like the way std::list uses its iterator).

Comment: If this is just an exercise you might want to code all of mentioned ways and even more if you come by any other interesting ideas. You could as well practice different ways of reacting to failure in deletion (like no element found -> return bool or enum, throw error etc). "Anywhere" might mean anything you want it to with this context as long as it makes sense. I'd add option to delete node at specified index as well.

Comment: Well if you have a not circular linked list, the values can be given a position numbers just like in array with list.front being 0 etc. So if you want to delete particular node you give it's position from front. Also if you are making any class or container, hide as many methods and variables you can and leave public only what needs to be public. In your case you should have public methods like front/back, enqueue/dequeue, insert, at etc. and all the pointers and actual data private.

Comment: "is it usual for a program using lists to actually manipulate pointers to the nodes?" Sort of. Look up "stl iterator".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In linked list you have constant time access to first element. So delete/insert anywhere means the place that exists between first and last element. Basically you need to have 2 iterators. When you find the place you want remove/insert a element, you should refer to the object just before it. because you have not access to the prev element, only to the next one:
Let's say our linked list looks like this:
*E0->E1->E2->E3->E4*

If you want remove E3, you need to have iterator set on E2 so that you could correct pointers for E2->next.

Good reference is the book Standard Library wrote by Nicolai M. Josuttis. The problem you have encountered is widely described there.

Answer (score 0):

```
node*insert(node*head,int d){

    node*temp=new node;
    temp->data=d;
    if(head==NULL){
        temp->next=NULL;
        head=temp;}
    else 
         {node*curr=head,*pre=NULL;
    while (curr!=NULL && curr->data<temp->data)
    {
        pre=curr;
        curr=curr->next;
    }
    temp->next=curr;
    if(pre==NULL)
        head=temp;
    pre->next=temp;
    }
    return head;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.